# Map array and display it?

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

```
$l = array(
               array("A"=>0.1,"B"=>1,"C"=>1,"D"=>1),
               array("A"=>0.1,"B"=>1,"C"=>0,"D"=>2),
            );

$h = array('h1','h2');
```

1-How Can I `map(l,h)`to this?

```
$result= $array(
               'h1'=> array("A"=>0.1,"B"=>1,"C"=>1,"D"=>1),
               'h1'=> array("A"=>0.1,"B"=>1,"C"=>0,"D"=>2),
            );
```

2- So I I can display(present html table)

```
-------------------
   | A | B | C | D  
-------------------
h1 |
-------------------
h2 |
--------------------
```

My trying to output:

```
<table>
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
  <tr>

  <tr>
}
<table>
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapping the array as you propose is easy:

```
$mapped = array_combine($h, $l);
```

Then:

```
// Print the top "headers" row
$columns = array_keys(reset($l));
echo '<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td>';
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// Print each data row
foreach ($mapped as $key => $row) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$key.'</td>';
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

// Done!
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: @Jon thank you so much ,why this line array_keys(reset($l)) ?

Comment: idk if the reset is necessary (probably good practice either way), but he's doing it for the 'A'.'B','C','D' column headers you have.  you shouldnt hardcode them in case you change the array later

Comment: @jon  whats up with your two opening `'td'` instead of `'<td>'`  is that typo or am i missing something?

Comment: @lEnAk, @jon_darkstar: `reset($l)` is a way of saying "the first item of `$l`" without having to specify its index as in `$l[0]`. This way it would work correctly even if `$l` did not have an item with the key `0` -- in this case no difference, but in general it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: oh righht.  since the pointer hadnt moved i was initially confused for why you would use it, but i forgot about the return value

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_combine($h, $l);
```

This works bc there are implied numeric indexes for the array elements, as you can see if you `var_dump($h)` or `var_dump($l)`

```
<table>
<?php
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>&nbsp</td>";
    foreach(array_keys($l[0]) as $letter)
        echo "<td>$letter</td>"; //A,B,C,D
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($result as $h_key=>$innerArr)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>$hkey</td>"; //h1,h2
        foreach($innerArr as $key=>$val)
           echo "<td>$val</td>";  //0.1, 1, etc.
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```